# Split Array of Files if exceeds the maximum limit

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, split

i want to split array of Files by size. I set a maximum size is 4MB.
If the total size <= max size, i add to new `List`.

Here my method :

```
public List<File> fileSplit(File [] files, long maxAttachmentSize) {
        int i = 0;
        long totalAttachmentSize = 0;

        List<File> list = new ArrayList<File>();
        for (int j = 0; j < files.length; j++) {
            File file = files[i];
            totalAttachmentSize += file.length();

            list.add(file);

            if (totalAttachmentSize > maxAttachmentSize) {
                //part += 1;
                break;
            }

        }

        return list;
}
```

And here is my array :

```
String [] attachments = {
                "/Users/fanjavaid/Documents/data.json",
                "/Users/fanjavaid/Documents/master.psd",
                "/Users/fanjavaid/Pictures/ceria.jpg",
                "/Users/fanjavaid/Desktop/All Data LM.dsv",     
                "/Users/fanjavaid/Desktop/LM August 01 - Now.xlsx",
                "/Users/fanjavaid/Desktop/Email_GoGreen.png",
                "/Users/fanjavaid/Desktop/Archive.zip",
                "/Users/fanjavaid/Desktop/Email_Veri2144202172009.zip",
                "/Users/fanjavaid/Desktop/Screenshot Collection.zip",
                "/Users/fanjavaid/Desktop/logo-big.jpg",
                "/Users/fanjavaid/Desktop/Mbak Putri.psd"
        };

        File [] files = convertToFile(attachments);
        Arrays.sort(files, SizeFileComparator.SIZE_COMPARATOR);
```

....
....

I invoke the method like this :

```
long maxAttachmentSize = 4194304; // in bytes
List<File> resultSplit = fileSplit(files, maxAttachmentSize);
```

The problem is it not return List as part. It just return all List. Not separated part by part.
How to handle that?

Thank you.

Comment: Paste your expected output please

Comment: for god sake, you add all files to a list what else do you expect?

Comment: My expected result is, for email splitter. So i just need some Lists that have every part of files. List_1 = file1, file2, file3 ... List_2 = file4, file5... and so on, which every List does not exceed the maximum size 4MB.

Comment: You are adding the file even before checking if the `totalAttachmentSize` will exceed `maxAttachmentSize` or not !!

Comment: @Neo I already check in this statement `if (totalAttachmentSize > maxAttachmentSize) {
                break;
            }`

Comment: If file1 and file2 are say 3.5 MB, file3 is 2MB, now your list will be file1,file2, file3. You need to check this before you decide to add. Also show us how your are invoking the `fileSplit` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that no file is bigger than max size, you can do this

```
public List<List<File>> fileSplit(File [] files, long maxAttachmentSize) {
  long totalAttachmentSize = 0;

  List<List<File>> allLists = new ArrayList<>();

  List<File> currList = new ArrayList<File>();
  allLists.add(currList);
  for (File file : files) {
    long fileSize = file.length();
    if ((totalAttachmentSize + fileSize) <= maxAttachmentSize) {
      currList.add(file);
      totalAttachmentSize += fileSize;
    } else {
      totalAttachmentSize = fileSize;
      currList = new ArrayList<File>();
      allLists.add(currList);
      currList.add(file); // assuming no file is bigger than maxAttachmentSize
    }
  }

  return allLists;
}
```

Comment: Just an observation: I think fanjavaid wanted the criteria to be <= maxAttachmentSize when adding the the current list.